# Kendo DateTimePicker: Need to return dates in UTC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

In my MVC application I am storing dates in UTC.  In my view I am doing this to show the dates in date time pickers in local time

```
<div class="datetimepicker">@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(m => m.StartDateTime).Value(Model.StartDateTime.ToLocalTime()))</div>
```

The problem is that when the datetimes arereturned in the post methods back to the server they are returned in local time.  Is there a way from the view to return the datetimes in UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi datetimepicker in kendo i dono abt it,but just a thought if u can get the value from datetimepicker and pass through a function as below which converts to UTC and then send it to server , i believe ur task is complete..sry if i am wrong...

```
function convertToUtc(str) {
    var date = new Date(str);
    var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
    var month = date.getUTCMonth()+1;
    var dd = dategetUTCDate();
    var hh = date.getUTCHours(); 
    var mi = date.getUTCMinutes();
    var sec = date.getUTCSeconds();

    // 2010-11-12T13:14:15Z

    theDate = year + "-" + (month [1] ? month : "0" + month [0]) + "-" + 
              (dd[1] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]);
   theTime = (hh[1] ? hh : "0" + hh[0]) + ":" + (mi[1] ? mi : "0" + mi[0]);
    return [ theDate, theTime ].join("T");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a good one and the approach that we suggest is covered in this code library [article](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/using-utc-time-on-both-client-and-server-sides.aspx).

Comment: That article is about using it in a kendo datagrid.  How would you do this with a datetimepicker?

Comment: Oh I thought the datepicker is in a Grid. Well basically when using the DateTimePicker with a regular submit - whatever you see in the KendoDatePicker the same will be submitted to the server. However on the server the same shift as the one described in the code library will be applied and you will need to specify the DateTime.Kind property.

Comment: I agree in principle, but I attempted to put it into practice and it proved very difficult.  When used in an MVC context, this particular control doesn't give you a lot of opportunity to manipulate its results.